# Backbone view output

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to output some h1 text on the page using backbone view but for some reason it is not working. I can show the h1 if i use it within document ready but not when I use it within the render function.

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:'body',
  intialize: function () {
    this.render();
    },
  render: function () {
    this.$el.empty();
    this.$el.append("<h1>My first Backbone app</h1>"); // not showing on the page
    return this;
    }
})
$(document).ready(function () {
  wineApp = new HomeView();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.el` is a DOM element while `this.$el` is a jQuery object. jQuery objects have an [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function which is not available for plain DOM elements.

You can also convert the DOM element into a jQuery object by running `$(this.el)`.

---

It's a typo: the function `intialize` should be called in *i* tialize. At the moment the function isn't invoked at all.

Comment: i tried this.$el.append("<h1>My first Backbone app</h1>"); but still not working.
   
    Also tried $(this.el).append("<h1>My first Backbone app</h1>"); but still not working.

Comment: @user1336103 Can you say what "not working" means? An error message? Does the h1 not show up on the page?

Comment: yep, h1 don't show up on the page when i try either this.$el or $(this.el) in render function.

Comment: i have updated the code above with your fix but h1 still not showing on the page

Comment: @user1336103 Works for me now, spotted a typo and updated the answer.

Comment: excellent - Thanks very much, i been trying so many different things and it was initialize misspelled. How did you detect that, is there any IntelliSense plugin or you just have a good eye :)

Comment: @user1336103  I set a breakpoint at `new HomeView();` and stepped through the backbone code. At some point I ended up in the default `initialize` function and wondered why it doesn't use the custom one. Btw, if you click the up arrow next to the check mark I get 10 internet points!

Comment: Thanks Matt, i am new to stackoverflow so don't have enough reputation to click arrow up at the moment, soon i have more than 15 reps i will click the arrow up :)

Comment: @user1336103 You're right, sorry, I didn't realize that you need reputation to upvote answers to your own questions.